# How to "keys %h" if $h is an object?

Tags: perl

`$h` below is an object, but it only contains a regular hash.

```
my $h = YAML::Syck::LoadFile('have_seen.yaml');
```

If it was a normal hash then the number of keys would just be `keys $h`.

**Question**

How to get the numbers of keys when the hash is in an object?

**Update**

This is code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use YAML::Syck;

my $h = YAML::Syck::LoadFile('h.yaml');

my $links = 100;

print $links - keys $h . "\n";
```

The yaml file contains

```
--- 
010711: 1
---
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$h` is not an object, but a plain hashref. This is really an operator precedence problem. Use parentheses to bind the argument to the `keys` function tight.

```
print $links - keys($h) . "\n";
```

As Greg Bacon pointed out, on old Perls it is necessary to manually dereference first with `%$h` or `%{ $h }` (which is the better style).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `keys` operator as in

```
print scalar keys %$h;
```

Most of the time, an explicit `scalar` is unnecessary, *e.g.*,

```
my $n = keys %$h;
```

But it’s usually a bad idea to go poking into the internals of an object. Use the public interface instead. Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: I have now tried both ways, and it fails with `Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref`. perldoc for `YAML::Syck` doesn't mention a method of how to get the numbers of keys, and I need the number of them. Have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

My code was also producing the same error `Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref` but the difference is that the hash was produced from my own object.

```
sub getAttributes {
  my $self = shift;
  return $self->{ATTRIBUTES};
}
```

I tried a few ways to get `keys` to de-reference what is returned by `$instance->getAttributes()` but it seems that once it has been blessed the keys function doesn't want to know.